# haskell and type definition of functions. couple of questions

Tags: haskell, function, types, definition, type-inference

if i do `any isUpper "asBsd"`, i'll get `True`.
here, the second element to `any` is a string.
but, if i do this:

```
any ("1" `isInfixOf`) ["qas","123","=-0"]
```

the second element to `any` is a list of strings.
how and why this difference between those 2 functions?

another example.
if i write `filter isUpper "asdVdf"` , i'll get `"V"`.
here, the second element to filter, is a string.
but, if i write this:
`filter (isUpper . head) ["abc","Vdh","12"]` , i'll get `["Vdh"]`.
as you can see, the second element to filter is now a list of strings.
why there is a differences and how haskell know's it's right in both cases?

to summarize it:
i don't understand how in the same function, one time haskell get a second element that is a string, and in other time, haskell get a list of strings, in the second element.
one time it happened in `any` function, and the other time in `filter` function.
how haskell(and me) know's it's right in both cases?

thanks :-).

Comment: What is the question exactly? Type inference is a major feature of Haskell, and any literals or even argument patterns will trigger it.

Comment: i don't understand how in one time haskell get a second argument that is a string, and in other time, haskell get a list of strings, in the second argument, and the both cases happend in the same function.  
one time in `any` and other time in `filter`.  
how haskell(and me) know's it's right in both cases?
i need an explanation of that :-)

Comment: This is a good question, and KennyTM's answer is excellent.  However it would help if you could edit the question to include your clarification.  That way anyone finding this question in future will be able to understand better.

Comment: edited.
i can change it to something else, if you think it's not clear :-).

Comment: Something that may come in handy. I don't know if this is just a feature of GHC or if all Haskell implementations do this, but you can type `:t <something>` to find out the type of something. For example if you type `:t any` you get: `any :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool`. So it takes a function of type `a -> Bool` and a list of `a`'s and returns a `Bool`.

Comment: yes, i know i can do that, but still i didn't understand why there are 2 different situations, that the same function get different second element, and for that i asked :-).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because `isUpper` is a `Char -> Bool` function and `"1" ‘isInfixOf‘` and `isUpper . head` are `[Char] -> Bool` functions

---

```
"1" `isInfixOf` xxx
```

can be rewritten as

```
isInfixOf "1" xxx
```

We knew the type of `isInfixOf` is `[a] -> [a] -> Bool`<sup>1</sup>.  Now the first argument to `isInfixOf` is `"1"` which is of type `[Char]`, so we can deduce `a` is a `Char`:

```
     isInfixOf :: [a]    -> [a] -> Bool
       "1"     :: [Char]
//∴ a = Char and
 isInfixOf "1" ::           [a] -> Bool
                =        [Char] -> Bool
```

That means `isInfixOf "1"` is now a `[Char] -> Bool` function.

Now, the type of `any` is `(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool` function. As above,

```
               any :: (a      -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
     isInfixOf "1" :: ([Char] -> Bool)
 //∴ a = [Char] and
```

any (isInfixOf "1") ::                     [a] -> Bool
                        =                [[Char]] -> Bool

In order to satisfy with the type constraint of `any (isInfixOf "1")`, the argument must be a string list.

---

Now consider `isUpper`. The type of `isUpper` is `Char -> Bool`. Hence:

```
              any :: (a    -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
          isUpper :: (Char -> Bool)
//∴ a = Char and
      any isUpper ::                   [a] -> Bool
                   =                [Char] -> Bool
```

So `any isUpper` needs to take a string only, instead of a string list.

---

Finally, `isUpper . head`. In Haskell, the types of the relevant functions are:

```
 filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
   head :: [a] -> a
isUpper :: Char -> Bool
    (.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
```

Hence for `filter isUpper`, `a = Char` and the type is `[Char] -> [Char]`, i.e. it needs to take a string as parameter.

And<sup>2</sup>:

```
            (.) :: (b    -> c   ) -> (a   -> b) -> a -> c
        isUpper :: (Char -> Bool)
           head ::                   ([b] -> b)
//∴ c = Bool, b = Char, a = [b] = [Char], and
 isUpper . head ::                                 a -> c
                =                             [Char] -> Bool
```

Thus for `filter (isUpper . head)`, we have `a = [Char]` and the type is `[[Char]] -> [[Char]]`, i.e. it needs to take a string list as parameter.

---

Note:

1. The type of `isInfixOf` is actually `(Eq a) => [a] -> [a] -> Bool` as the equality must be valid for type `a`, but this is irrelevant in our analysis.
2. I've temporarily changed the variable `a` to `b` for `head`, but it doesn't matter.

Comment: first of all, thank you very much for great answer, and very detailed one!.
i think i get what you say, but i have one question.
in `filter (isUpper . head)` , `a = [Char]`, and because the type signature of filter is `filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]` , the `(a -> Bool)` function is realy a `([Char] -> Bool)` function, and because of that we should have `[[Char]]` in the second element of `filter`, because if `a` is actually `[Char]` thus `[a]` is actually one level "above" `a`, which should be `[[Char]]`.
am i right?

thanks a lot :-)

Comment: one more thing, i dont know what is `isIndexOf` or `indexOf` in your answer. i assumed that you confused this with `isInfixOf` , so when i saw `indexOf` , i replaced it with `isInfixOf` for my understanding.
if i'm wrong, please tell me :-).

Comment: @moshe: Yes. And yes, `isInfixOf`.

Answer (score 5):

A String is actually just  list of characters, a `[Char]`. So if you like, "hello" is shorthand for `['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']`. Therefore in both cases, you're getting a list of something, it's just that one case is a list of Char and the other case is a list of Strings (or a list of lists of chars, if you like).

Answer (score 4):

Well, that's polymorphism. The type of `any` is `(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool` where the type variable `a` can be anything you like. In the first case it's `Char` - because the second argument is a list of `Char`s - and the type becomes `(Char -> Bool) -> String -> Bool` (remember that `[Char]` is the same as `String`!); in the second `a` is `String` and the type becomes `(String -> Bool) -> [String] -> Bool`.

The reasoning for `filter` is similar.